# Configuring Tomcat's JDBCRealm with Oracle DB - what is correct tables structure?

Tags: oracle, tomcat, authentication

Trying to configure this bunch - but got 403 Error.

Tables description:

```
SQL> desc tmc_users_names;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 USER_NAME                                 NOT NULL VARCHAR2(100)
 USER_PASS                                          VARCHAR2(100)
 DESCRIPTION                                        VARCHAR2(100)

SQL> desc tmc_users_roles;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 USER_NAME                                 NOT NULL VARCHAR2(100)
 ROLE_NAME                                 NOT NULL VARCHAR2(100)
```

Have roles table in Oracle database:

```
SQL> select * from tmc_users_roles;

USER_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ROLE_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
setevoy // IRL - here is other data from SSL certftificate
cert
```

Have users table:

```
SQL> select * from tmc_users_names;

USER_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
USER_PASS
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
setevoy // IRL - here is other data from SSL certftificate
```

In `server.xml` have:

```
<Realm  className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm"
driverName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
connectionURL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@dbserver:1521:shname"
connectionName="tmc" connectionPassword="password"
userTable="tmc_users_names" userNameCol="user_name" userCredCol="user_pass"
userRoleTable="tmc_users_roles" roleNameCol="role_name"
```

And `web.xml`:

```
<login-config>
<auth-method>CLIENT-CERT</auth-method>
</login-config>
<security-role>
<role-name>cert</role-name>
</security-role>
```

As I understand - due to authentification process Tomcat must call database, get `tmc_users_names` table, get `user_name` from it, then call `tmc_users_roles`, and compare `user_name` and `role_name`, correct?

But - I got 403.

And - if I'm use another database scheme (with `views` instead of usual `table`) - it works.

I got scheme for current tables from official man-page Tomcat (there is for MySQL - but I think there is no difference for Tomcat?).

So - what is correct tables structure for Oracle database? Only with `views`? It seems to me - all must be more easier...

P.S. Why I don't use scheme which works? Because - I did not created it and I don't know how it works. Thats why I try to make it myself - to get understanding of this authentification process.

Thanks for tips.

Comment: Not sure if this is the reason it doesn't work, but you need a factory in the Realm I think. factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory". Also unrelated, but it's safer to use "digest=..." so you can store  encrypted passwords. Otherwise I see no issue with the given config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget to run:

```
SQL> commit;
Commit complete.
```

After adding entries in to Oracle tables... :-)